# Objectify: querying for content of foreign keys

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have three entities as Human, Dog, Treat. The Treat entity has the key `Key<Dog>`, and the Dog entity has the key `Key<Human>`. When I query for Treat, I want a response that contains the actual Entity for Dog, and the entity for Dog must contain the actual entity for Human: as opposed to just the keys. How do I do that?

**update**

So I would like to be able to execute the following two queries

- `getAllTreats()` should return a list of all treats, where through each treat I can access Dog data and then through said Dog data find Human data.
- Given a Treat id, I would like to retrieve that Treat with it's Dog data and with the said Dog's Human data.

Code: (I gave pgiecek +1 because he mentioned the @Parent notation. But the problem still remains, at least for the single Treat by treatId)

```
@Entity
public class Human {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class Dog {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Load
    @Parent
    private Ref<Human> human;
}


@Entity
public class Treat {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Load
    @Parent
    private Ref<Dog> dog;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Ref<?>` along with `@Load` annotation instead of `Key<?>`. The `Ref<?>`  works just like a `Key<?>` but allows you to directly access the actual entity object. Furthermore, the `@Load` annotation enables you to load associated entity objects more efficiently.

Here you can find more details on [Ref<?>](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities#refs) and on [@Load](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities#load).

**Update**

Query 1

```
List<Treat> treats = ofy.load().type(Treat.class).list()
```

For each `Treat` object you have to access `Dog` reference and fetch it manually via `Ref<?>.get()` method. The same applies for `Human`. However, you can use `@Load` annotation for your parent fields.

Query 2

If you have only ID of a `Treat`, it is not possible to load the entity because the all ancestor path is actually the key of the entity.

> The complete key identifying the entity consists of a sequence of
>   kind-identifier pairs specifying its ancestor path and terminating
>   with those of the entity itself.

In your case the Treat's key looks like follows.

```
Key = [Human:ID, Dog:ID, Treat:ID]
```

In order to retrieve a concrete `Treat` instance, you need to know either its ID along with all parents (`Dog` and `Human` instances/IDs in your case) or its key. Look at `Key<?>.toWebSafeString()` and `Key<?>.create(String)` (or `Key<?>.valueOf(String)`) methods that may help you to serialize the key into `String` and restore it later.

```
Treat treat = ... // create a new instance along with its parents

String webSafeKey = Key.create(treat).toWebSafeString();

// do whatever you need

Key<Treat> treatKey = Key.<Treat>create(webSafeKey);

Treat loaded = ofy.load().key(treatKey).now();
```

Comment: +1 for your response. But there is a problem: the way ancestor query works seems to require me to know the ancestor in advance and then from top down effect my query (i.e. from root to leaf). But what happens if all I have is a treat id? How do I get a Treat that contains a Dog, which in turn contains a Human?

Comment: Can you update your qustion so that it contains exact relationship between your entities? You did not mention ancestor paths.